# Snowflake's time difference alternative to Postgres INTERVAL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have UNIX duration in ms, that needs to be converted to human readable format. In Postgres it is possible to do using INTERVAL type, but how can it be done in Snowflake? The challenge is that some of those values can exceed 24h. I've checked solution to a similar problem (with adjustments to ms) on Snowflake [forum](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007pkflnSAA/time-difference-in-hour-minute-and-seconds). But it doesnt support time > 24h.

Sample data:

```
7200000 -- 2h
28800000 --8h
1800000 -- 30min
252000000 -- 70h
86400000 -- 24h
3593314 -- 59min 53sec
```

So that the desired output would look like:

```
02:00:00
08:00:00
00:30:00
70:00:00
24:00:00
00:59:53
```

Maybe I am bad at searching, but so far I wasnt able to find a solution for this issue.

Solution that works in Postgres `SELECT time_unix::bigint * INTERVAL '1 ms'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
    ,floor(ms/3600000) as hh
    ,floor((ms%3600000)/60000) as mm
    ,floor((ms%60000)/1000) as ss
    ,nullifzero(hh) as a1
    ,nullifzero(mm) as a2
    ,nullifzero(ss) as a3
    ,trim(nvl(a1||'h ','') || nvl(a2||'m ','') || nvl(a3||'s','')) as r 
from values
    (7200000, '2h'),
    (28800000 , '8h'),
    (1800000, '30min'),
    (252000000, '70h'),
    (86400000, '24h'),
    (3593314, '59min 53sec')
    t(ms, wanted)
```

gives:

| MS | WANTED | HH | MM | SS | A1 | A2 | A3 | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7,200,000 | 2h | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |  |  | 2h |
| 28,800,000 | 8h | 8 | 0 | 0 | 8 |  |  | 8h |
| 1,800,000 | 30min | 0 | 30 | 0 |  | 30 |  | 30m |
| 252,000,000 | 70h | 70 | 0 | 0 | 70 |  |  | 70h |
| 86,400,000 | 24h | 24 | 0 | 0 | 24 |  |  | 24h |
| 3,593,314 | 59min 53sec | 0 | 59 | 53 |  | 59 | 53 | 59m 53s |

thus:

```
select *
    ,trim(nvl(nullifzero(floor(ms/3600000))||'h ','') || nvl(nullifzero(floor((ms%3600000)/60000))||'m ','') || nvl(nullifzero(floor((ms%60000)/1000))||'s','')) as r 
from values
    (7200000, '2h'),
    (28800000 , '8h'),
    (1800000, '30min'),
    (252000000, '70h'),
    (86400000, '24h'),
    (3593314, '59min 53sec')
    t(ms, wanted)
```

gives:

| MS | WANTED | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7,200,000 | 2h | 2h |
| 28,800,000 | 8h | 8h |
| 1,800,000 | 30min | 30m |
| 252,000,000 | 70h | 70h |
| 86,400,000 | 24h | 24h |
| 3,593,314 | 59min 53sec | 59m 53s |

### OR I could read:

```
select *
    ,trim(nvl(nullifzero(floor(ms/3600000))||'h ','') || nvl(nullifzero(floor((ms%3600000)/60000))||'m ','') || nvl(nullifzero(floor((ms%60000)/1000))||'s','')) as r 
    ,lpad(floor(ms/3600000), 2, 0) || ':' || lpad(floor((ms%3600000)/60000), 2, 0) || ':' || lpad(floor((ms%60000)/1000), 2, 0) as r2
from values
    (7200000, '2h'),
    (28800000 , '8h'),
    (1800000, '30min'),
    (252000000, '70h'),
    (86400000, '24h'),
    (3593314, '59min 53sec')
    t(ms, wanted)
```

| MS | WANTED | R | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7,200,000 | 2h | 2h | 02:00:00 |
| 28,800,000 | 8h | 8h | 08:00:00 |
| 1,800,000 | 30min | 30m | 00:30:00 |
| 252,000,000 | 70h | 70h | 70:00:00 |
| 86,400,000 | 24h | 24h | 24:00:00 |
| 3,593,314 | 59min 53sec | 59m 53s | 00:59:53 |

Comment: Unfortunately this solution only works with time that is below 24h

Comment: You mention greater than 24h what do you want to happen?

Comment: That one works well, but your initial suggestion (before edit) was only working with times below 24h. Nevertheless, thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Wondering if someone can come up with a worse solution :)

```
create or replace function pginterval( TIME number )
returns varchar
language sql
as
$$
select  LPAD( (extract( day from to_timestamp( TIME, 3 )) - 1 ) * 24 + extract( hour from  to_timestamp( TIME, 3 )), 2, '0' )
|| ':' || right( to_timestamp( TIME, 3 )::time, 5 )
$$;

select pginterval( x )
from values 
(7200000),
(28800000),
(1800000),
(252000000),
(86400000),
(3593314) tmp (x);
```

| PGINTERVAL( X ) |
| --- |
| 02:00:00 |
| 08:00:00 |
| 00:30:00 |
| 70:00:00 |
| 24:00:00 |
| 00:59:53 |